# How to start jscodeshift in inspect mode?

Tags: jscodeshift, codemod

This used to be runnable but recently I'm encounter the following issue.

By running the following command:

> node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/.bin/jscodeshift mod.js file.

I am encountering this problem

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/7e57a2d3-0885-44b3-b51e-b47dc8417d87
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Processing 1 files... 
Spawning 1 workers...
Sending 1 files to free worker...
Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use
All done. 
Results: 
0 errors
0 unmodified
0 skipped
0 ok
Time elapsed: 0.035seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me:

1. Start **node-inspector**
2. Install **jscodeshift** in my local **repo** as a **dev** dependency.
3. put **debugger** statement in my script
4. run jscodeshift via node with `--debug-brk` arg and added `--run-in-band` jscodeshift param. 
   For example :- 
   I entered node

   `--debug-brk ./node_modules/jscodeshift/bin/jscodeshift.sh -t my-refactor-script.js --run-in-band`

If you add a file pattern at the end, it works fine, which in the case of debugging is helpful when you want to test just one trouble file.

I did not test debugging `jscodeshift` installed via `npm -g`

Comment: `--run-in-band` was the trick for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer that worked for me was installing `ndb`, https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/ndb, and prefixing the command with it.

> ndb node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/.bin/jscodeshift mod.js

Answer (score 0):

The reason inspect mode doesn't work is because another process (e.g. another instance of the inspector) is already using the default port (`9229`), so they're conflicting. Either use a different port for the inspector or kill the process that's currently using the port.

If you use a different port, you'll be able to start the inspector. Just pass the desired port-number (e.g. `39479`) to `--inspect-brk`.

Your example:
`node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/.bin/jscodeshift mod.js file.`

Could for example be: `node --inspect-brk=39479 ./node_modules/.bin/jscodeshift mod.js file.`

DANGER: If you need the port 9229, you can kill the process/inspector that's currently using that port, but if you don't know what that process is doing you could damage things: `lsof -i TCP:9229 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`

Comment: That other process seems to be the one just ran.

Comment: Could you update your question to include the exact command you're using? Based on the question, it looks like the transform-flag isn't being passed: `--transform ./path/to/the/codemod.js`